# How to save input texture in gstreamer plugin

Tags: plugins, save, textures, gstreamer

I've written a gstreamer plugin. It is based on GstGLFilter. I want to save the input texture in the function "filter_texture". This saved texture will be operated with the next input texture. How can I save the input texture?

Comment: The `in_tex` is a pointer `GstGLMemory` structure that has a `tex_id` which is an OpenGL id of the texture, so you can use the usual OpenGL to copy that texture. Or use some GStreamer `gst_gl_memory_*` wrapper functions that do the same (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-libs/html/gst-plugins-bad-libs-GstGLMemory.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I have already generated a texture in this element. I want to copy the in_tex to this texture. How can I do this? Which OpenGL Api should I use?